# Draw a fragment only when have a certain state

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose, android-lifecycle

I have a fragment, part of which consists of XML widgets and part of ComposeView. There are two states based on which I draw the Compose UI:

```kotlin
sealed interface State {
    object Empty : State
    data class Content(val items: List<String>) : State
}
```

In the ViewModel I store a StateFlow which is initially initialized by State.Empty, and then State.Content is asynchronously emitted into it.

```
class ViewModel {
    private val mutableStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<State>(State.Empty)
    val stateFlow = mutableStateFlow.asStateFlow()

    init {
        scope.launch {
            ...
            viewStateFlow.emitAll(State.Content(list))
        }
    }
}
```

What happens: an empty fragment opens for me and after a while the content suddenly appears from Compose. I want to do the following: show the fragment only after StateFlow stores the State.Content. How can I do it?

Maybe some state checks before onCreateView()?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think doing some state checks before you launch the fragment would be good you can do something like:

```
    val job = scope.launch {
        
        viewStateFlow.emitAll(State.Content(list))
    }
```

then check `job.isActive` before you insert the fragment.

Comment: In the example above, I have a stateFlow that I can check in a fragment, like: 
`if (stateFlow.value is State.Empty) {}`.
The question is more about how to implement this check, because onCreateView() will be executed only once when creating a fragment, but State.Content is set only after for a while

Comment: For example, in the first second I have the State.Empty state and do not want to display the fragment, and in the second I have State.Content and now I want to show the fragment. The problem is that `OnCreateView()` is called once, and I need to somehow wait until StateFlow contains State.Content

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a coroutine in `OnCreate()` or `OnCreateView()`.

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        viewModel.stateFlow.collect { state ->
            if (state is State.Content) {
                // Content has arrived
            }
        }
    }
}
```